# Understanding shap.decision_plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, shap

Recently I started using SHAP. I really liked the way they explain the contribution of each feature in the model.
I somehow face difficulty to understand the decision plot.
I could not find explanation about this plot
I would be thankful if someone explain the plot below because I am a bit confusing about the base value and the model output.
Usually I see in decision plot all the lines starting at same point from bottom and then they separate based on feature contribution.
 
Is it always like that? Because my plot is different in this case.
And also, does the blue color means positive influence and the red is negative?
Many thanks in advance for any sharing ideas with me to understand the plot.
Regards

[image: shap.decision_plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already you should check out the documentation notebook at: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/notebooks/plots/decision_plot.ipynb is talks about the coloring.

As for why the lines don't start at the bottom in your plot, I think that is because there are more features that are cut off. I could imagine summing all those features and showing them combined like in the SHAP waterfall plot, but that would need to be coded up (feel free to open that as an issue or PR for that if you like).